# R foreach: Read and manipulate multiple files in parallel

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel, mclapply

I have 500 tar.xz files containing 2000 csv files. I need to untar them a few tar files at a time (because of disk space), process them into a data.table, delete the csv files from disk and then save the result as RDS before moving on to the next few tar file.

My function works fine in serial but in parallel it gets the files mixed up between cores. Why is this?

Some sample data:

```
    for(j in 1:5){
     for(i in 1:5){
      a<-df[sample(x = 1:nrow(df), size = 50, replace = TRUE),]
      write.csv(a,paste0("seed_",i,".csv"))
      lf<-list.files(pattern=".csv")
                  }
     tar(tarfile = paste0("seed_",j,".tar"),files = lf,compression = c("xz"), tar="tar")
                 }
```

**Example code with foreach**

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
require(magrittr)

#List all tar files in directory
list_of_files<-list.files(pattern = ".tar")

  packsINeed<-c("vroom","magrittr","dplyr","tidyr","doParallel")
    
  #Start for loop

myCluster<-makeCluster(6,type="PSOCK")
registerDoParallel(myCluster) 

  foreach(i= 1:NROW(list_of_files),.packages = packsINeed)%dopar%{

print(paste(list_of_files[i], "which is", i, "of", NROW(list_of_files) ))

print("2. Untar .csv files inside")
 untar(tarfile = list_of_files[i], exdir = "tempOutputFiles")



 print("#3. Read in files and add up two columns")
df<-vroom::vroom(list.files("tempOutputFiles/$.csv"), id="path")

df$A<-df$B+df$C

    print("#4. save RDS")

saveRDS(object = df, file = paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(list_of_files[i], compression = TRUE),".rds"))

 print("#5. Clean up files")

.files<-list.files("tempOutputFiles",pattern=".csv")

    file.remove(basename(.files))
}
```

**Using mclapply - behaves the same**

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
require(magrittr)

#List all tar files in directory
list_of_files<-list.files(pattern = ".tar")
```

myParFun<-fun(filename){

```
print(paste(filename))

print("2. Untar all .csv files inside")
 untar(tarfile = filename, exdir = "tempOutputFiles")



 print("#3. Read in files and add up two columns")
df<-vroom::vroom(list.files("tempOutputFiles/$.csv"), id="path")

df$A<-df$B+df$C

    print("#4. save RDS")

saveRDS(object = df, file = paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(filename, compression = TRUE),".rds"))

 print("#5. Clean up files")

   .files<-list.files("tempOutputFiles",pattern=".csv")

    file.remove(.files)
}

mclapply(FUN=myParFun, list_of_files, mc.cores=4)
```

Based on Waldi's comment I've created a directory for each file in list_of_files and it now works fine. But is there snore approach? Using tempdir for example?

Comment: Could you provide some code at least to understand how you designed your code?

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this. I've added the bare-bones of the loop. What I actually do with the files takes quick a while but this is just an example.

Comment: This looks weird: `file.remove(basename(.files))`. The files are already base names, and I think they shouldn't.

Comment: Ah that's because untar gives full path I think. I'm finding that files get deleted before one whole loop has finished which is very strange.

Comment: Here (`files<-list.files("tempOutputFiles",pattern=".csv")`) you get all csv files from this directory (but only basenames, there is a parameter if you want to get full paths).

Comment: I agree, but all the processors put their files in tempOutputFiles and I only want to delete the files belonging to that particular processor. I.e. core 1 is dealing with seed_1_*.csv while core two is dealing with seed_10_*.csv, do you know what I mean?

Comment: By the way, I've read your online help articles quite a bit, it's very nicely written!

Comment: Why do you untar all the files in the same directory `tempOutputFiles`? Creating one specific temporary directory per process would avoid the problem you're encountering.

Comment: @Waldi makes sense but do you know why? I though a new instance of the code was sent to a processor where it stays until finished... Could you offer a how to for the directory creation please?

Comment: Yes, I could provide an example, but I need one clarification : if I understand correctly, `list_of_files[i]` is a .tar file, you untar it, but why do you use vroom on the same `list_of_files[i]` instead of on the resulting .csv files?

Comment: Ahhh my mistake, I'm sorry. It should of course be a subset of the csv files that have been extracted.

Comment: Maybe `Sys.getpid()` would allow you to assign a unique temporary directory using process information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, the code below creates one directory per process / tar file, untars, merges the CSVs in a .rds file and deletes them.
Note that it seems that `vroom` needs the `altrep = FALSE` argument to avoid a [permission denied error](https://github.com/r-lib/vroom/issues/177) at deletion.

```
# Generate sample tars for test
write.csv(mtcars,'file1.csv')
write.csv(mtcars,'file2.csv')
write.csv(iris,'file3.csv')
write.csv(iris,'file4.csv')
tar('tar1.tar',files=c('file1.csv','file2.csv'),tar="tar")
tar('tar2.tar',files=c('file3.csv','file4.csv'),tar="tar")

require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
require(magrittr)

#List all tar files in directory
list_of_files<-list.files(pattern = "\\.tar")

packsINeed<-c("vroom","magrittr","dplyr","tidyr","doParallel")

#Start for loop

myCluster<-makeCluster(2,type="PSOCK")
registerDoParallel(myCluster) 

foreach(i= 1:NROW(list_of_files),.packages = packsINeed)%dopar%{
  print(paste(list_of_files[i], "which is", i, "of", NROW(list_of_files) ))
  
  print("2. Untar .csv files inside")
  fileout <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(list_of_files[i], compression = TRUE)
  exdir <- paste0("temp",fileout)
  untar(tarfile = list_of_files[i], exdir = exdir)
  
  print("#3. Read in files and add up two columns")
  df<-vroom::vroom(file.path(exdir,dir(exdir,"*.csv")),altrep = FALSE)
  
  # df$A<-df$B+df$C   # These columns don't exist in mtcars used as example
  
  print("#4. save RDS")
  
  saveRDS(object = df, file = file.path(exdir,paste0(fileout,".rds")))
  
  print("#5. Clean up files")
  
  .files<-list.files(exdir,pattern="\\.csv")
  
  file.remove(file.path(exdir,.files))
}
```

Not sure where the .rds should go, so left for the time being in the temporary folder.